# How to pass parameters to a function by doing checks

Tags: java, android, function, parameters

I am a beginner in Android (Java) development and I came across a code that is not very pleasing to me. Could anyone help me and tell me if  **is there a more elegant way to pass the required parameters to a function and with fewer object checks**  than the one mentioned below?

Notice that for each parameter there are several checks for the existence of a given object. And the worst thing is that multiple checks are repeated.

```
DAO.inserirEvento(db, uuid_evento.toString(), enco_id,
                evento.getTipo(),
                evento.getStatus(),
                dataCompleta,
                evento.getHora(),
                evento.getCriacao(),
                evento.getDestino() == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0) == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0).getEndereco() == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0).getEndereco().getCodigo(),
                evento.getDestino() == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0) == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0).getEndereco() == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0).getEndereco().getCep(),
                evento.getDestino() == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0) == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0).getEndereco() == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0).getEndereco().getLogradouro(),
                evento.getDestino() == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0) == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0).getEndereco() == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0).getEndereco().getNumero(),
                evento.getDestino() == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0) == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0).getEndereco() == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0).getEndereco().getLocalidade(),
                evento.getDestino() == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0) == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0).getEndereco() == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0).getEndereco().getUf(),
                evento.getDestino() == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0) == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0).getEndereco() == null ? null : evento.getDestino().get(0).getEndereco().getBairro());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `Optional` to make it less ugly.

```
Optional.ofNullable(evento.getDestino())
        .map(d -> d.get(0))
        .map(d -> d.getEndereco())
        .map(e -> e.getCodigo())
        .orElse(null)
```

Each of these `Optional`s will be empty if any of the functions return `null`.

Also, given that `getCodgio()` is the only line that changes, you may wish to extract everything up to and including `d.getEndereco()` into a local `Optional<Endereco>` (or whatever type it is) to reduce repetition.

(Note: this assumes that `evento.getDestino()` cannot be an empty list.)

Comment: Got it! It's a good solution though, it's only available for Api Level 24 on Android. I'm giving support to Api Level 16. Would you know any other compatible way?

Comment: To be totally honest, anyone who has a device that is still on Level 16 should seriously consider getting an upgrade, as I'd be surprised if any manufacturers of devices that old are still sending security updates (among other things).